# Bash Deployment Script Permission Problem

Tags: bash, scripting, deployment

I'm writing a deployment script and have run in to a strange problem...

```
ian@baster:~$ sudo echo "Build: "$REVISION" - Deployed: "$(date +%Y-%m-%d) > /home/www/prod/www/revision.html
-bash: /home/www/prod/www/revision.html: Permission denied
```

but...

```
root@baster:~# echo "Build: "$REVISION" - Deployed: "$(date +%Y-%m-%d) > /home/www/prod/www/revision.html
root@baster:~# more /home/www/prod/www/revision.html
Build:  - Deployed: 2011-01-28
```

then...

```
ian@baster:~$ sudo ls -l /home/www/prod/www
total 28
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       31 2011-01-28 21:56 revision.html

ian@baster:~$ sudo more /home/www/prod/www/revision.html
Build:  - Deployed: 2011-01-28
```

What's the deal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `echo` is run as root, but not the redirection. Run the redirection in a sudo subshell.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to do that is with `tee`:

```
echo "foo" | sudo tee filename
```

You can suppress the output to the screen which `tee` does like this:

```
echo "foo" | sudo tee filename >/dev/null
```

Comment: Is that really the usual way? I generally just do `sudo sh -c 'echo blah > file'`

Comment: @KeithThompson: Either way works, the advantage of using a pipeline as I have shown is that the `sudo tee` can be easily added to the end of an existing pipeline and you have a choice of outputting to stdout again.

Comment: Or `sudo dd of=filename`.